# compiling the bibliography

Tags: bibliographies

I try to show my list of references at the end of the text without including sources by themselves, but it seems to me that latex doesn't see a proper file. I use biber for that purposes

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt]{article}

%%% Работа с русским языком
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}   %% загружает пакет многоязыковой вёрстки
\usepackage{fontspec}      %% подготавливает загрузку шрифтов Open Type, True Type и др.
\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures={TeX},Renderer=Basic}  %% свойства шрифтов по умолчанию
\setmainfont[Ligatures={TeX,Historic}]{Times New Roman} %% задаёт основной шрифт документа
\setsansfont{Comic Sans MS}                    %% задаёт шрифт без засечек
\setmonofont{Courier New}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\frenchspacing
\renewcommand{\epsilon}{\ensuremath{\varepsilon}}
\renewcommand{\phi}{\ensuremath{\varphi}}
\renewcommand{\kappa}{\ensuremath{\varkappa}}
\renewcommand{\le}{\ensuremath{\leqslant}}
\renewcommand{\leq}{\ensuremath{\leqslant}}
\renewcommand{\ge}{\ensuremath{\geqslant}}
\renewcommand{\geq}{\ensuremath{\geqslant}}
\renewcommand{\emptyset}{\varnothing}

%%% Дополнительная работа с математикой
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amssymb,amsthm,mathtools} % AMS
\usepackage{icomma} % "Умная" запятая: $0,2$ --- число, $0, 2$ --- перечисление

%% Номера формул
%\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs=true} % Показывать номера только у тех формул, на которые есть \eqref{} в тексте.
%\usepackage{leqno} % Нумерация формул слева

%% Свои команды
\DeclareMathOperator{\sgn}{\mathop{sgn}}

%% Перенос знаков в формулах (по Львовскому)
\newcommand*{\hm}[1]{#1\nobreak\discretionary{}
{\hbox{$\mathsurround=0pt #1$}}{}}

%%% Работа с картинками
\usepackage{graphicx}  % Для вставки рисунков
\graphicspath{{images/}{images2/}}  % папки с картинками
\setlength\fboxsep{3pt} % Отступ рамки \fbox{} от рисунка
\setlength\fboxrule{1pt} % Толщина линий рамки \fbox{}
\usepackage{wrapfig} % Обтекание рисунков текстом
\usepackage{calc}
%%% Работа с таблицами
\usepackage{array,tabularx,tabulary,booktabs} % Дополнительная работа с таблицами
\usepackage{longtable}  % Длинные таблицы
\usepackage{multirow} % Слияние строк в таблице
\newcommand{\pinys}{\ensuremath{^\circ}}
%%% Теоремы
\theoremstyle{plain} % Это стиль по умолчанию, его можно не переопределять.
\newtheorem{theorem}{Теорема}[section]
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Утверждение}

\theoremstyle{definition} % "Определение"
\newtheorem{corollary}{Следствие}[theorem]
\newtheorem{problem}{Задача}[section]
 
\theoremstyle{remark} % "Примечание"
\newtheorem*{nonum}{Решение}

%%% Программирование
\usepackage{etoolbox} % логические операторы

%%% Страница
\usepackage{extsizes} % Возможность сделать 14-й шрифт
\usepackage{geometry} % Простой способ задавать поля
    \geometry{top=30mm}
    \geometry{bottom=40mm}
    \geometry{left=30mm}
    \geometry{right=20mm}
 %
%\usepackage{fancyhdr} % Колонтитулы
%   \pagestyle{fancy}
    %\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}  % Толщина линейки, отчеркивающей верхний колонтитул
%   \lfoot{Нижний левый}
%   \rfoot{Нижний правый}
%   \rhead{Верхний правый}
%   \chead{Верхний в центре}
%   \lhead{Верхний левый}
%   \cfoot{Нижний в центре} % По умолчанию здесь номер страницы

\usepackage{setspace} % Интерлиньяж
\onehalfspacing % Интерлиньяж 1.5
%\doublespacing % Интерлиньяж 2
%\singlespacing % Интерлиньяж 1
\usepackage{lastpage} % Узнать, сколько всего страниц в документе.
\newcommand{\hyi}[2]{\addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{#2}}
\usepackage{soul} % Модификаторы начертания

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table,rgb]{enumitem,xcolor}
\hypersetup{                % Гиперссылки
    unicode=true,           % русские буквы в раздела PDF
    pdftitle={Заголовок},   % Заголовок
    pdfauthor={Автор},      % Автор
    pdfsubject={Тема},      % Тема
    pdfcreator={Создатель}, % Создатель
    pdfproducer={Производитель}, % Производитель
    pdfkeywords={keyword1} {key2} {key3}, % Ключевые слова
    colorlinks=true,        % false: ссылки в рамках; true: цветные ссылки
    linkcolor=black,          % внутренние ссылки
    citecolor=black,        % на библиографию
    filecolor=magenta,      % на файлы
    urlcolor=blue          % на URL
}
\renewcommand\contentsname{Содержание}
\usepackage{csquotes} % Еще инструменты для ссылок
\usepackage{multicol} % Несколько колонок

\usepackage{tikz} % Работа с графикой
\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage[style=authoryear,maxcitenames=1,backend=biber,sorting=nyt]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bib1.bib}
\begin{document}
bla bla bla
\nocite{}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: You have posted a lot of code but most of it unrelated to the question and we can not run it and test anything .  but if you want to reference the entire bib file you need `\nocite{*}` not `\nocite{}`